# Extracting numbers from the file part of a URL

Tags: php, regex, xml, url, numbers

I have some sitemaps like this:

```
http://subdomain1.myweb.com/6.xml
http://subdomain2.myweb.com/t2.xml
http://myweb.com/t2.xml
```

So, how do I extract the numbers 6, 2 and 2? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a URL parser for starters.

Comment: Use a url parser and a regular expression.

Comment: `\d+` or `\d+(?=\.xml)`

Comment: Not enough data for a good answer - what happens with files with names like `abc123xrt34.xml` - would you want all of the numbers, some of the numbers, the last set of numbers? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
$str = basename("http://myweb.com/t2.xml", "");
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);
```

Comment: Hello, Your code worked like a charm. However, I edited my question. It has subdomain with number. So, how to fix it ? Sorry for my mistake. Thanks !

Comment: Please check my new answer. replay me

Comment: it worked but it shown answer in print_r($matches[0]); where $matches[0] returns array.

Comment: Hello, if url doesn't contain subdomain, it will not work. Can you fix for 2 cases (subdomain and only main domain), please ?

Comment: Please check my new answer. replay me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/.com\/([a-z A-Z])?(.*?).xml/is',$sourcestring,$matches);
```

the array $matches[2] return your output.
I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Hello, it is great but when I use echo $matches[2]; it showed nothing. Also, if my domain is .info, .net,.... it will not work. How to fix it ? Thanks !

Comment: use print_r($matches[2]) in place of echo $matches[2].
surely it will work.